# Who can teach me how to reach the StackProfile method in ArcEngine10.2?

Tags: arcgis-engine

I try my best to write code to get it.

The codes list below, but I think I don't understand these parameters so that I can't run the gp Tool successfully. So I want to consult someone who can tell me how to write correctly.

```
 private void AddSection(IFeatureLayer linFeatureLayer, IRasterLayer pRasterLayer,string name)
    {
        Geoprocessor gp = new Geoprocessor();
        gp.OverwriteOutput = true;
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Analyst3DTools.StackProfile sfsf = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Analyst3DTools.StackProfile();

        sfsf.in_line_features = linFeatureLayer;         
        sfsf.profile_targets = pRasterLayer;
        sfsf.out_table = @"C:\Users\Haker\Desktop\section\StackProfile5.dbf";
        sfsf.out_graph = @"C:\Users\Haker\Desktop\section\newgraph";
         try
        {
            gp.Execute(sfsf,null);
        }
        catch (COMException e)
        {
            string message = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < gp.MessageCount; i++)
            {
                message += gp.GetMessage(i) + "\r\n";
            }
            MessageBox.Show(message + e.ToString());
        }}
```

Comment: Please add more detail (what are you trying to do, what error did you get or what didn't work, what kind of data did you use...)